# Linux, how to rows that share the same column value in a table?

Tags: linux, command

I have an input table that is something like:

```
chr21    10861860    10862010    0.004580    1235 
chr21    10896160    10896310    0.008635    928
chr21    10936080    10936230    0.004542    50 
chr21    10972180    10972330    0.008600    1235
chr21    11059120    11059270    0.008133    2002 
chr21    11101660    11101810    0.008360    468 
chr21    11181780    11181930    0.004310    928
```

And I need a Linux command able to print out only the rows of this table that share a common element in the last column.
In the example, I need this command to print out:

```
chr21    10861860    10862010    0.004580    1235 
chr21    10896160    10896310    0.008635    928 
chr21    10972180    10972330    0.008600    1235  
chr21    11181780    11181930    0.004310    928
```

That are the rows that have duplicate elements in the last column
What command may I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort the data on the fifth column.

```
$ sort -n -k5,5 data-file > file1
```

Next write an [awk](http://www.softprayog.in/tutorials/awk-tutorial) script to process file1. If the fifth field is the same as that of previous line, write to output.

If you want to preserve the order of final output the same as input, add a unique key (say, line numbers) to the initial input and sort the final output based on the line numbers.